Standard Oil, American Tobacco, & The Sherman Anti-Trust Act
On pg.260 (towards the bottom) of Howard Zinn's A People's History of the United States Zinn says,

"In later years it would refuse to break up the Standard Oil and American Tobacco monopolies, saying the Sherman Act barred only 'unreasonable' combinations in restraint of trade."

I assume the court cases being referenced are Standard Oil Co. of New Jersey v. United States (1911) and United States v. American Tobacco Co. (1911) respectively. However, it was my understanding that the result of these court cases was the dissolution of Standard Oil into 43 separate companies and the dissolution of American Tobacco into 4 different competitors (in accordance with the fact that each company transgressed beyond what was allowed for by the rule of reason). How can one reconcile these two points of view?
--EDIT--
I was asked to include further information and to clarify my question:

Relevant information pertaining to my edition of Zinn can be found at this google books link

The quote was taken from chapter 11 on pg. 260. It's the last sentence of the fourth paragraph from the top down. Dale M asked what the antecedent of "it" is. If you read the paragraph, the antecedent is "the Court" (which by itself in isolation would be ambiguous). However, given that the discussion from the preceding paragraph is about the Supreme Court (and the phrase "the Court" capitalizes as a proper noun), this leads me to believe Zinn is referring to the Supreme Court (see image below).




Provided Zinn was referring to the Supreme court cases I mention (boldfaced above), can someone please reconcile the two accounts presented. I thought it was true that in each of the two Supreme Court cases, Standard Oil and American Tobacco were subsequently dissolved into smaller companies. However, it appears that Zinn is claiming to the contrary when he says, "In later years it would refuse to break up the Standard Oil and American Tobacco monopolies, saying the Sherman Act barred only 'unreasonable' combinations in restraint of trade."

Either Zinn is referring to the court cases I mention, and is incorrect in making the claim he does, or perhaps he is referring to earlier Supreme Court cases wherein it was decided NOT to dissolve the two companies in question. Notice how he does not explicitly reference the name of any court cases with an italicized parenthetical like he did with U.S. v. E.C. Knight Co. or with Pollock v. Farmer's Loan & Trust Company.



What is the question? I've read this three or four times and I don't quite understand what you are attempting to ask.  The question is much more likely to get an answer if it is clear what you want to know.   Please revise the title to ask a question. What points of view?  Please include your preliminary research.

What is “it” in the quote?

I know page numbers are standard citing technique we are all trained to do in school. However, you need to also cite which edition. A lot of people may have a paperback copy, which may well have completely different page count. Also, while I have the book (perhaps even with the same page numbering as you) it'll be a while before I get off work and can go thumb through it physically. For these reasons, I'd like to see here an expanded quote from the text, and perhaps a chapter name/number. People shouldn't have to take a trip to their library to be sure what we're talking about here.

@DaleM: SCOTUS .

@T.E.D.: I know page numbers are standard citing technique we are all trained to do in school. ... People shouldn't have to take a trip to their library Actually nowadays we just use Google and/or search in the ebook. In this case one can also easily find the full book online: https://theanarchistlibrary.org/library/howard-zinn-a-people-s-history-of-the-united-states https://www.historyisaweapon.com/defcon1/zinnbaron11.html

@user182601 - That's kind of my point. Find me "page 260" either of those. You can't really, because the kinds of resources we are likely to have access to here aren't organized that way. Yes, you can still find the quote by searching for that, but the point is that the page number, in the context of this website, is rather useless information. A link to the work online (such as you provided) is far and away more useful. If I instead have a paper edition (but perhaps not OP's) I'm far more capable of finding it if they had told us "in Chapter 11".

@T.E.D.: And my point is that instead of nitpicking trivial flaws (by a new contributor), you could've just copy-pasted a few words, Googled, and very quickly found all the information you wanted.

The original post has been updated, incorporating suggestions made and then some. So if anybody has pertinent commentary regarding my question, I would greatly appreciate them sharing.
